# Why is $|x-y|\le \delta$

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. The author proves every $k$-cell is compact. However, I have a fundamental query regarding the proof.

> Let $I$ be a $k$-cell consisting of all points $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3....x_k)$ such that $a_j\le x_j\le b_j (1\le j\le k)$. $$\delta=(\sum\limits_{1}^{k}(b_j-a_j)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
>   Then $|x-y|\le\delta, \text{ if }x\in I, y\in I$

Now, the problem is, each interval is of length $r_i$, say. Then the overall length of the interval, say $L$ can be related as follows: $L\ge \sum_{1}^{k}r_k\ge (\sum\limits_{1}^{k}(r_i)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

To put it more succinctly with an example, $I=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}\implies\delta=\sqrt 2$.
$|3.99-1.01|=2.98\nless \sqrt2$.

What am I not understanding? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Each $|x_i - y_i| \leq b_i - a_i$ by construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $I$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $x$ and $y$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^k$. It could be written as $I=[a_1,b_1]\times [a_2,b_2]\times\cdots\times[a_k,b_k]$. So in your example, you should actually have something like $I=[1,2]\times [3,4]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Thus $1.01$ and $3.99$ are not elements of $I$.

Comment: Damn. Thanks. I missed that.